# jQuery Show/Hide - Make other elements have a smoother transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

Is there a way for the label/form below the 'myContent' div to have a smoother transition when I am hiding/showing it?

Currently, when the myContent div is toggled, the other elements below it 'jump' into place - it would be great if I could figure out a way to slide them up into their correct location.  What do you think?

### JavaScript

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    jQuery("#" + divId).toggle("slide", {
        direction: "up"
    });
}

function ShowThing(divID) {
    jQuery("#" + divID).show("slide", {
        direction: "up"
    }, 500);
}

function HideThing(divID) {
    jQuery("#" + divID).hide("slide", {
        direction: "up"
    }, 500);
}
```

### HTML

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;">Toggle Button</a>

<button onclick="ShowThing('myContent');">Show</button>
<button onclick="HideThing('myContent');">Hide</button>
<div>
    <div id="myContent" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;">The content in this div will hide and show (toggle) when the toggle is pressed.
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="cool-field">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cool-field" id="cool-field" />
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

[**Click Here for jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mysteryos/C3tLs/1/)

Optimized the javascript so that all code is based on jQuery.

**HTML code**

```
<a href="#" style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 10px;" class="togglebtn">Toggle Button</a>

<button id="showthing">Show</button>
<button id="hidething">Hide</button>
<div>
    <div id="myContent" style="background-color: #aaa; padding: 5px 10px;">The content in this div will hide and show (toggle) when the toggle is pressed.
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="cool-field">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="cool-field" id="cool-field" />
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function(){
    $('a.togglebtn').click(function(){
        $('#myContent').stop().slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
    $('#showthing').click(function(){
        $('#myContent').slideDown(500);
    });
    $('#hidething').click(function(){
        $('#myContent').stop().slideUp(500);
    });    
});
```

Comment: You changed it to $ but I have read that I should use jQuery instead of $ to avoid conflicts?

Comment: IF you do have other javasript libraries that use the $ as a function or variable name, then yes. Also, you'll have to use jQuery.noConflict() function to make jQuery relinquish its control of the $ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is blank.

Instead of `show()` you can use `slideDown('slow');`
for `hide` you can use `slideUp('slow');` Also you can set direction.

Otherwise you can use [JQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)